# Bibtex started showing only [?]

Tags: bibtex

my bibtex stopped showing refrences. It shows now only '[?]'. The story is like this. I use pdfLatex within the TexWorks. It worked all right. But after i added extra couple of new refs in the bib file, it did not want to show them in the text and showwed only [?]. ted the .AUX files. And it stopped showing ALL refs...just [?]'s. What can i do about it?

Comment: Duplicate of [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: Have you looked for error messages in bibtex's log file (it has the same file name as your .tex file but with .blg extension)?

Comment: What did you change before this occured?